Convergence of conformal metrics with prescribed curvature
We know that for any function $K: \mathbb{D} \to \left[-a, -b\right]$, where $a, b > 0$, there is a unique metric $h$ on the disk $\mathbb{D}$ which is conformal to $dz^{2}$, and has curvature equal to $K$ (see for example this paper). If $h = e^{\rho} h_{-1}$ (where $\rho$ is a function and $h_{-1}$ is the hyperbolic metric), one can use the generalized maximum principle and the PDE
$K_{h} = e^{-\rho} (-\Delta_{h_{-1}} \rho - 1)$
(where $\Delta_{h_{-1}} \rho$ is the Laplacian of $\rho$ with respect to the hyperbolic metric) to show that:

If $h_{n}$ is a sequence of conformal metrics that have curvatures $K_{h_{n}}$ which belong to the interval $\left[-a, -b\right]$, and $h$ is a conformal metric that has curvature $K_{h}$ belonging to the interval $\left[-a, -b\right]$, and $K_{h_{n}}$ converge smoothly and uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$ to $K_{h}$, then $h_{n}$ converge in $C^{0}$ to $h$.

My question is: what about more regularity? Specifically, is the following statement true?

Is it true that under the previous assumptions, the metrics $h_{n}$ converge smoothly and uniformly on compact subsets to the metric $h$?

